# Authoritive Pages - broken page

Tags: search, error, authoritative-pages

I was configuring the Authoritative Pages from the CA Search Administration page. I wanted to increase the relevance of the internal Intranet and SharePoint site and reduce the relevance of the file shares.

So I put "file://*" in the secondary relevance box, clicked OK and an error message came up "unknown URL" (or similar).  I removed that and tried to save again and got the same error message.

Now, whenever I back on the click on that link I get `ERROR: Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed. Correlation ID: 5f2c35b0-269d-4e45-96d4-7d65745f2f63` and in the event log I get the same error being repeated.

Any way I can remove this setting?  Any chance with Powershell maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce this.  Perhaps try putting in a valid value and saving, maybe that will clear it for you.

On a side note, this file shares would like be something you would want to demote as a non-authoritative site versus putting it in the 2nd or 3rd level authoritative pages.

Comment: Ta help - I ended up deleting and rebuilding the search service from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found of getting around this was to delete the search application and recreate it. And that was tricky in itself.

Pro Tip: Delete all the components from the "Topology page" before deleting the application service.